# Can a junction box be used to extend all wiring to main panel?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I own a cabin that's been broken into and stripped of anything of value.  Unfortunately that means they ripped the copper out of the main panel, including come few feet of the cable above the box.

What I'm wondering is, can junction boxes be added near the panel in order to extend all cable to the panel?  I understand there are fill requirements that would result in a fairly large or several jboxes, I'm just not clear if this would be allowed close to the panel / and or any other code requirements.  It's prohibitive to repull all that cable.

Comment: Cannot state code, but my electrician did add a j-box a few inches from the panel for some cables.  I know the panel itself can be used as a junction box, so should not be a problem with a line of boxes beside/on top of it.  Should have labels on cables/boxes to make finding circuits easier, 3 or 4 cables going in and out of a box could be confusing.

Comment: Thanks @crip659!  That's my understanding as well, that essentially a jbox is fine near the panel.  It's quite common it seems to do this for one or two shorter cables, also an easy way to add an outlet next to your panel.  What I'm really hung up on is that this would be for all electrical.  Just seems kind of crazy.

Comment: With my heavy-up, we thought we'd need something like that. In the end, my electrician managed to get all but one existing circuit moved over. That one initially used a 4" box as a junction, but that was ugly - I suggested moving it slightly to be able to connect it to the new main panel with a nipple. In the end, he ran a new cable (only ~ 10 feet) and now the former panel area is a nice big empty section of wall waiting to be filled with...something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

This is often how it works when you want to move a panel.

You put large junction boxes near the location of the original panel and then junction the circuit to the location of the new panel.

The junction boxes will have to remain accessible though.

Comment: That's great news.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I had exactly that problem, and that's what I did.

Use steel junction boxes - they're easier to work with for this task, since they're designed to mount several different ways and have a variety of inlet and outlet options.  A simple so-called 3/8" Romex connector will bring Romex into a standard knockout hole.  Conduit can also dock to the knockout holes, they are the 'universal donor'.

**Neutrals must be kept separate! Do not splice all neutrals together!** Neutral is not common and it is not ground!  However all grounds can be spliced together.

I ran EMT metal conduit from the panel to new junction box locations, then ran the individual circuits in THHN wires -- marked so I knew which neutral was paired to which hot(s).  This meant all cables coming in could simply ground to the metal junction box, and the EMT conduit would carry ground to the panel.  That reduced the number of splices in the box.   For conduit more than 2' long, there is a 4-circuit limit inside each conduit. (3 circuits for 30A and above).

In counting the number of circuit splices per box, a little bit of math is involved.

- Count each wire that isn't a ground.  Each #14 wire counts as 2 cubic inches.  Each #12 is 2.25 cubic inches. Each #10 is 2.5 cubes.  Each #8 is 3 ci.  Each #6 is a big 5 c.i.
- Grounds are "4 for the price of 1". *
- Give 1 count of the largest wire size *per box* to allow for all cable clamps.

A cable is several wires wrapped in a sheath.

So for example suppose we have two 12/2 cables we must extend.  That is the 4 wires from the cables + the 4 wires from the extensions.  There are also 4 grounds, but those count as "4 for the price of 1" so they count as 1.  Then you have 1 count to cover **all** the cable clamps.   That is a total of 10 wire counts.  They are all #12, so total cubic inches needed is 22.5 cubic inches.

---

For boxes, you have a variety of options.

- The common 99 cent 4x4x1.5" box is 21 cubic inches per the rules.
- You can get extension boxes (that size box with an open back designed to stack on an existing box).
- The deeper 4 x 4 x 2.125" box is 30 cubic inches.
- The larger 4-11/16" (120mm) square  box is 42 cubic inches*
- They also make 6x6 boxes that are enormous, obviously.

The 4-11/16" (120mm) box is better bought at electrical supply houses; I find big-box stores nastily overcharge.

---

* That is a NEC 2020 rule. Under NEC 2017, all grounds together counted as 1 count (the largest size present).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how many circuits you're talking about but an easy solution would be to get a 4"x4"x18" trough and mount it above your main panel. They come with knockouts or not if you choose to punch your own holes. These make all the splicing and extensions easy without all the cable cramming into smaller junction boxes.

Here's an example from Gordon electrical supply, who i'm not affiliated with in any way.
[image]